# Creating auto update on php

Tags: php, auto-update

I have more than 10 php website. 
My problem is everytime I have an update,I have to make a changes manually for each website
Is there any better way?
Thanks

Comment: impossibly broad.

Comment: ServerFault.com might be a better place to ask about automating server updates.